# Popover controller for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uipopovercontroller

I am working on iPhone application. And I want to create popover controller for my app. It is only available for iPad applications. Please help.

Comment: you can't use the popOver in iPhone App. You can take the image like as popover & set it as a background image for the view.

Comment: I use this one https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController, check it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it, i have live app with with popover in iPhone.
Just You have to create interface for popover

**NSObject+UIPopover_Iphone.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIPopoverController (overrides)
+(BOOL)_popoversDisabled;
@end
```

**NSObject+UIPopover_Iphone.m**

```
#import "NSObject+UIPopover_Iphone.h"

@implementation UIPopoverController (overrides)

+(BOOL)_popoversDisabled
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```

and now just import `NSObject+UIPopover_Iphone.h`  in your Viewcontroller.h

for Reference check this [Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iykxemuxbk)

Comment: Thanks. Its working. But will it create any problem while uploading to app store. Do apple reject this or not?

Comment: Have you used in live application? Is it approved by apple?

Comment: Yes, my app is approved n live in appstore.

Comment: Not sure if you really need to import in your work file. If you already added it to target build, then it will just work.

Answer (score 0):

**As stated in Apple's Documentation**

`Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices`.

So there is no way to use this class in iPhone application unfortunately. But there are a couple of custom third-party implementations of the functionality provided by UIPopoverController which add iPhone support and more.

You can check this [Link](https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover) for example.

Comment: Or [this one](https://github.com/runway20/PopoverView)

Comment: This is no longer true with iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use open source framework for it
for example https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover