# Popover view for iPhone using XCode 5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, foundation

I wanted to reuse the popover for iPhone described in [this video](http://youtu.be/1iykxemuxbk) which is exactly what I need.

The problem is that I couldn't bind a `UIViewController` property to the popover's `UIViewController` like in the video.

One difference with the video is that it has been made using XCode 4.2 and I'm using XCode 5.

So the question is: How to make a popover for iPhone like in the [video](http://youtu.be/1iykxemuxbk) on XCode 5?

[Here is the XCode 5 project I am struggling with.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uydduvx71prw4y8/UIPopoverIphone.zip)

Comment: I tested this popover feature on iPhone 4s iOs8.1 simulator and I got a black screen blocking the app :( apparently the code below is not working anymore from iOs8 ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured out a way to get popover to work on iPhone and iPad programmatically !

- Create a category to make popover available on iPhone (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787765/uipopovercontroller-for-iphone-not-working))

  ```
  //UIPopover+Iphone.h
  @interface UIPopoverController (overrides)
  + (BOOL)_popoversDisabled;
  @end

  //UIPopover+Iphone.m
  @implementation UIPopoverController (overrides)
  + (BOOL)_popoversDisabled { return NO;
  }
  @end
  ```
- Create the button which will show the popover and implement the method it calls

**ExampleUIViewController.h**

```
@interface ExampleViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
    @property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *detailButton;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPopoverController *poc;
```

UIPopoverController poc has to be held in an instance variable, more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895071/uipopovercontroller-dealloc-reached-while-popover-is-still-visible).

**ExampleUIViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    _detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_detailButton addTarget:self
                action:@selector(showPop:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:_detailButton];
}

-(void)showPop:(UIButton *)button {
   UIViewController *detailsViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
   self.poc = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:detailsViewController];
   [self.poc setDelegate:self];
   [self.poc presentPopoverFromRect:_detailButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
}
```

- Create the UIViewController that will contain what's displayed inside the popover (called DetailsViewController in the example)

Simply create it in your project by a right click -> New File -> Objective c class -> UIViewController and tick the box "With XIB".

Then a popover will appear right next to the button when tapped.

Tested OK on iOs5 and above.

Comment: how to add any object to this pop over view

Comment: The content of the popover, in my example, is DetailsViewController. So to add anything into the pop over view, add it to your DetailsViewController.

Comment: Ya, I got, I used this, [myViewController.view addSubviews:objects];

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205903/popover-controller-for-iphone it has been accepted by Apple. As for myself I didn’t submit my app to the App Store yet.

Comment: I tested this popover feature on iPhone 4s iOs8.1 simulator and I got a black screen blocking the app :( apparently this code is not working on iOs8 and probably all versions above...

Comment: Hey Seb, I am also seeing black screen on iOS 8.1 simulator, did you resolve the issue?

Comment: I ended up using an other solution : I made the view appear above the others and set some animations (fading and translation) so it looks nice when the view comes to the screen.