# iOS- How to add objects in a popoverController in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uielement

In my app, I have a button, when it is clicked a popoverView will be displayed.
I used the following code
First, I added UIPopover+Iphone.h and UIPopover+Iphone.m files from the link  [Popover view for iPhone using XCode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238526/popover-view-for-iphone-using-xcode-5)

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
   UIViewController *popoverViewController=[[UIViewController alloc]init];
   UIPopoverController * popoverController=[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popoverViewController];
popoverController.popoverContentSize=CGSizeMake(200, 200);
   [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:timingTextField.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

I got an output like this
[image]

Now I want to insert some objects in it, say a button or some other equivalent UI element. Can anyone please suggest me something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the elements you want to your `UIViewController *popoverViewController`. this is the `viewcontroller` that is displayed in `PopoverController * popoverController`.

Comment: then show the code where you add the elements. in your code you add an empty view controller.

Comment: What U say is this,right, [popoverViewController addSubview:button];

Comment: I cant use this at all

Comment: yes. but before you add the button you have to initialize the button correct with the correct value for his frame

Comment: It is showing an error No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'addSubview:'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43405/discussion-between-chandru-and-thorb)

Comment: you have to call [popoverViewController.view addSubview:yourButton]

Comment: I have 5 text fields in my view, but i need to use this in only one field. I used the above code in textfieldBeginEdition metjod, I get an error, wen I click other fields also this popover view is displayed