# Alert needs to show as popover within iPhone

Tags: iphone, swift, uipopovercontroller

The view customization:

As UIAlertController shows in iPad in popover style. Is it possible to show alert as popover within iPhone devices as well?

Comment: do you want to show alertcontroller as alert style?

Comment: The Obj-C code to show alert using alertcontroller is :    `UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert Title" message:@"Alert message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];`

Comment: Need to show alert as popover style.

Comment: There is no popover style for iPhone. You may need to create custom viewController and animate it as popover in iphone.

Comment: Also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18206309/5997339.